# Two ObservableCollections in one viewmodel using one ItemsSource from Xaml

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I'm trying to add an expandable listview to an existing project. The problem is that I already have an ObservableCollection that is fetching data from ItemsSource in Xaml. So, somehow, I need to add another ObservableCollection without getting error. Ambiguity between....

```
public ObservableCollection<Data> listData { get; set; }
```

That ObservableCollection is connected to this class:

```
public class Data : ObservableCollection<ClassModel> 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Title;
    }       
}
```

The above code is working fine. When I add this it will not work:

```
 public ObservableRangeCollection<ContinentViewModel> listData { get; private set; }
    = new ObservableRangeCollection<ContinentViewModel>();
```

This is my ItemsSource from Xaml:

```
 <ListView
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            ItemsSource="{Binding listData}"/>
```

Worth mentioning is that I already have a baseclass in my viewmodel.

Im following this github repo to implement expandable listview: https://github.com/my-jabin/ExpandableListView-Xamarin

Thanks in advance!